# LNK 2019 - Unresolved External Symbol

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am getting the below link errors.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: NowHook, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Compiling...

1>NowHook.CPP
1>Linking...

1>NowHook.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__VirtualProtect@16 referenced in function "void __cdecl 

1>NowHook.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__GetProcAddress@8 referenced in function "void __cdecl 

1>NowHook.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__LoadLibraryA@4 referenced in function "void __cdecl HookSend(void)" (?HookSend@@YAXXZ)

1>C:\Users\JAGAN\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\HookNow\Debug\NowHook.dll : 
fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals

1>Build log was saved at "file://c:\Users\JAGAN\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects
```

I have included
1) Linker/General/AdditionalLibraryDirectories
2) Linker/Input/Additional Dependencies

Answer (score 3):

You are missing kernel32.lib in your Linker/Input/Additional Dependencies

Make sure you are setting the Additional Dependencies for "All Configurations" and "All Platforms".

[image]

Comment: I have included kernel32.lib in the Linker/Input/Additional Dependencies.But no remedy the same error repeats.

Comment: You probably added that in one platform (e.g. X64) and then building another platform (e.g. X86)

Comment: Could you pls eloborate.I am having windows 7 - 64 bit.VS build is showing 32bit.

Comment: @Jagan Updated the answer with a screenshot

Comment: @Harvey.Thanks a ton :).I tried that too and didn't work.Finally installed VS 2010 express and it took care of all the additional library dependencies.And now no linking errors.