# unresolved external symbol _loadlibrarya_@4 and _getprocaddress_@8 in Fortran

Tags: windows, dll, fortran, unresolved-external

I have problems with Fortran when accessing external DLL. I'm not familiar with Fortran. Error showing here `stdcall external LoadLibraryA, GetProcAddress`. The code as below:

```
Subroutine GetDLLEntryPoint (EntryPoint,ModuleName)
   stdcall external LoadLibraryA, GetProcAddress  !error here
   integer*4 LoadLibraryA, GetProcAddress
   integer*4 pl,  plvalue, EntryPoint
   integer *4 pm
   character*100 LibraryName, ModuleName
   EntryPoint=0
   LibraryName = "MY.DLL"//char(0)
   pl = loc(LibraryName)
   plvalue = LoadLibraryA(val(pl))
   if (plvalue.ne.0) then
   pm = loc(ModuleName)
   EntryPoint = GetProcAddress (val(plvalue), val(pm))
   endif
   RETURN
   end
```

The error in the Absoft Fortran compiler is:

```
 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _loadlibrarya_@4

 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _getprocaddress_@8
```

Comment: Qhich compiler do you use? Tgis is not standard Fortran. If you are not Familiar with Fortran, is it someone else's code? Did it work before? In which compiler?

Comment: I changed the compiler to absoft. now show different error. yes someone else's code. i need to test the code.

Comment: So which compiler is it originally supposed to work with? Could you tell which compiler gave you the previous error? Which version of the compiler?

Comment: If you compile 32-bit see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11481633/lnk-2019-unresolved-external-symbol If you compile 64-bit, stdcall shouldn't do much. How do you specify the libraries you link? Do you use Visual Studio?

Comment: Previously I use Silverfrost with F95.

Comment: Ok, did you have a look at the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11481633/lnk-2019-unresolved-external-symbol  Have you tried the solution?

Comment: @VladimirF are u able to share with me some code example on how fortran accessing dll? I'm trying to create from scratch right now.

Comment: You can find many examples on this site by searching. There are many more on the internet. Have you tried the solution I linked? I have asked you several questions and you have not replied.

Comment: yes already tried but no luck.

Comment: And the other questions I asked above? And what exactly have you tried? And what happened thereafter?